# Match error while using view

Tags: scala, view, pattern-matching

```
List(1,2,3,4).sliding(2).map({ case List(a, b) => a < b }).forall(identity)
```

compiles and returns `true` (albeit with a warning that the match is not exhaustive).

```
List(1,2,3,4).view
   .sliding(2).map({ case List(a: Int, b: Int) => a < b }).forall(identity)
```

compiles (so long as we include the type annotations for `a` and `b`) but throws a MatchError:

```
scala.MatchError: SeqViewC(...) (of class scala.collection.SeqViewLike$$anon$1)
        at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:12)
        at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:12)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.next(Iterator.scala:335)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.forall(Iterator.scala:663)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.forall(Iterator.scala:333)
```

Why?

Comment: `sliding` returns an `Iterator`, so calling it on a `view` doesn't offer any gain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's interesting, the list extractor `List.unapplySeq` is not able to extract `SeqViewLike` objects, which is why you get a match error. But on the other hand `Seq` can. You can see that like this:

```
scala> val seqView = List(1,2).view.sliding(2).next
seqView: scala.collection.SeqView[Int,List[Int]] = SeqViewC(...)

scala> val List(a, b, _*) = seqView

scala.MatchError: SeqViewC(...) 

scala> val Seq(a, b, _*) = seqView
a: Int = 1
b: Int = 2
```

So a fix to your second line would be:

```
List(1,2,3,4).view.sliding(2).map({ case Seq(a, b) => a < b }).forall(identity)
// res: Boolean = true
```

So the issue is that `List(1,2,3,4).view` returns a `SeqView`.

Note that `sliding` already returns an `Iterator`, so List(1,2,3,4).sliding(2) is lazy is that sense. May be `view` is not necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Well, a view of a list is not a list, it is a SeqView, which is a Seq.  The following does the right thing:

```
List(1,2,3,4).view
   .sliding(2).map({ case Seq(a: Int, b: Int) => a < b }).forall(identity)
```